# How to rerender item by clicking on it expo js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo

I have a flatlist with rendered list of items. I need for each item to change circle to checked-circle on click and go back on second click. I tried to do it with changing item prop isChecked but circle doesn't rerender until I go out of the screen and came back. How may I fix my problem?

Here is my rendering code:

```
const renderItems = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => (item.isChecked = !item.isChecked)}
    style={
      item.isMarked
        ? {
            backgroundColor: '#FE2C55',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: word_height
          }
        : { flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', height: word_height }
    }
  >
    <View
      style={{
        width: 45,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#F6FFE0'
      }}
    >
      {item.isChecked ? (
        <Feather name="check-circle" size={25} color="#3D5201" />
      ) : (
        <Feather name="circle" size={25} color="#3D5201" />
      )}
    </View>

    <View style={styles.word_line}>
      <View style={{ width: word_width, paddingLeft: 20 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{item.word}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: word_width, paddingLeft: 20 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{item.translation}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Comment: can you provide your whole js/jsx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line, you are trying to mutate the props variable, so react will not update the component when the props state is mutated.

```js
onPress={() => (item.isChecked = !item.isChecked)}
```

To do this, create a separate component (based on the name of the `renderItems` method, I guess it's just a function in the component) and add state to it.

Use `useState` and the initial state value that was taken from the props `initialIsChecked`

```
const Item = ({isMarked, isChecked: initialIsChecked, word, translation}) => {
 const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(initialIsChecked);

 const handleClick = () => {
   setIsChecked((prev) => !prev);
 };

 return (
   <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={handleClick}
     style={
       isMarked
         ? {
             backgroundColor: '#FE2C55',
             flexDirection: 'row',
             alignItems: 'center',
             height: word_height,
           }
         : {flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', height: word_height}
     }>
     <View
       style={{
         width: 45,
         justifyContent: 'center',
         alignItems: 'center',
         height: '100%',
         backgroundColor: '#F6FFE0',
       }}>
       {isChecked ? (
         <Feather name="check-circle" size={25} color="#3D5201" />
       ) : (
         <Feather name="circle" size={25} color="#3D5201" />
       )}
     </View>

     <View style={styles.word_line}>
       <View style={{width: word_width, paddingLeft: 20}}>
         <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{word}</Text>
       </View>
       <View style={{width: word_width, paddingLeft: 20}}>
         <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{translation}</Text>
       </View>
     </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
 );
};
```

Then the list component should look something like this:

```
const List = () => {
  return <ScrollView>
    items.map((item) => (
      <Item
          key={item.id} // if there is id
          isMarked={item.isMarked}
          isChecked={item.isChecked}
          word={item.word}
          translation={item.translation}
      />
    )
  </ScrollView>;
};
```